# Запуск программы в форме

Tags: c#, ооп, условия

Доброго времени суток.

Вот появился подобный вопрос, как на C# можно подобное реализовать? И можно ли вообще. Пишется изолированное приложение, нужно запускать ехе файл из под терминала, на котором доступно только это приложение. Будет отдельная вкладка, в которой и нужно запустить стороннее приложение. Встраивать уже написанное не получится, слишком сложно переписывать.

заранее, благодарю за ответ

Comment: Вы имеете в виду отображение консольного вывода другой программы внутри окна, которым владеет программа на C#? Можно, по идее, например, средствами WinAPI.

Заметьте, что не каждая программа обладает консолью или окном, так что ваша задача в общем случае может и не иметь смысла.

Comment: Именно, Некая программа в программе. 

Есть какие-либо линки на это? Я просто не понимаю, каким образом это можно реализовать. Может примеры.

Answer (score 3):

Поможет WinAPI

```
/// <summary>
/// Позволяет привязать любой объект имеющий свой handle 
/// в качестве дочерного МДИ-окна
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hWndChild">Дескриптор привязываемого окна</param>
/// <param name="hWndNewParent">Дескриптор куда привязываем</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

Следующий пример в теле класса формы привязывает окно стороннего процесса, к панели panel1. Можно привязывать напрямую к форме, но в моей практике так оказалось удобней. Обратите внимание на ожидания - они могут понадобиться, могут нет "зависит от..."

```
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exepath);
//Здесь может понадобиться ожидание 
// Thread.Sleep(1000);
if (proc.WaitForInputIdle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds))
{
   //Здесь тоже может понадобиться ожидание 
   //Thread.Sleep(2000);
   SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, this.panel1.Handle);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Process.Start("C:\\WinAsm\\WinAsm.exe");
```

или

```
Process.Start(@"C:\WinAsm\WinAsm.exe");
```